# Exchange server 2007 - ExchangeServiceBinding::UpdateItem failed

Tags: exchange-server, exchange-server-2007

For `ExchangeServiceBinding::UpdateItem` on Exchange 2007 got the following error message :

*When making a request as an account that does not have a mailbox, you must specify the mailbox primary SMTP address for any distinguished folder Ids.*

When I skipped `ExchangeServiceBinding::UpdateItem` into code and only apply `ExchangeServiceBinding::SendItem` got the following error message :

*The user account which was used to submit this request does not have the right to send mail on behalf of the specified sending account*

Made mailbox for credential user, but it doesn't help.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps for solution :

1. Make mail box for credential domain user on Exch 2007
2. On Exchange server 2007/RC/Mailbox, credential user has to be added into Mannage Full Access Permission and Properties/Mail Flow Settings/Delivery Option/Grant for monitored account/mailbox.